# Are there any downsides to calling Activity.finish(), startActivity(), startActivityForResult() anywhere else besides in the Activity itself?

Tags: android, performance, coding-style

I have a project that I am working on that is currently calling the Activity methods just about all over the place. (eg. my CameraActivity is calling startActivityForResult() in its JpegPictureCallback, another activity is having startActivityForResult() called in one of its Views, and yet another has one of its button's onClickListeners call finish() )

I am new to Android, but some of this practice seems *odd* to me. Especially when I have had to explicitly give a child view or onClickListener the parent Activity just so it can call such methods. Usually when I have to go out of my way like that to make something work, there is usually a better way to do it.

Also calling startActivityForResult() in one class and having onActivityResult() returning in another class seems counter intuitive. It seems to not form a logical flow of information.

Specifically my questions are:

- Is there a performance impact to calling Activities in this way?
- Is this proper coding style? (Both personally, but specifically according to some well-defined guidelines i.e. Android's dev guidelines)

Answer (score 0):

1. No there is no performance impact in calling activities this way.
2. Yes this is the standard coding style. Refer the link below for the coding standard.

For detailed info check : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html